# Redirecionando o conteúdo do Adobe XD no WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, embed

A empresa onde eu trabalho contratou alguém para fazer um dashboard simples usando o Adobe XD.

Exemplo: https://xd.adobe.com/view/67c0b3a6-f0e6-4f67-a209-e41767311939/

Mas nós gostaríamos de hospedar o dashboard no nosso site, que foi desenvolvido usando o WordPress. Isso é possível? Acredito que soluções envolvendo embedding da página com o dashboard no WordPress (provavelmente mais fácil) ou de alguma forma importando o programa Adobe XD em nossa página do WordPress (não sei se é possível) seriam válidas. Obrigado!

Comment: Vocês podem usar o `iframe` ou desenvolver essa função em seu site (que é bem simples, por sinal).

Comment: Eu tentei usar o iframe, mas não consegui fazê-lo funcionar. Eu usei o código abaixo, mas não funciona:

<iframe src="https://xd.adobe.com/view/67c0b3a6-f0e6-4f67-a209-e41767311939/"></iframe>

Já este funciona:

<iframe src="http://www.weather.gov/"></iframe>

Qual o motivo?

Comment: Olhei agora e eles informaram o header `X-Frame-Options:DENY` que significa que nenhum site pode "embedar" esse conteúdo (nem mesmo eles). Nesse caso você pode desenvolver uma versão ou linkar para o site. Provavelmente os termos deles não permite muito além disso.

Comment: Linkar para o site não resolveria o problema, pois o que queremos é apresentar o dashboard dentro do nosso domínio da empresa (sem o link do Adobe). O que seria desenvolver uma versão? Não ficou muito claro pra mim. Obrigado.

Comment: Da uma olhada na documentação oficial. https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/share-embed-designs-prototypes.html outro link do Fórum da Adobe como questionamentos similares https://www.google.com.br/search?q=export+adobe+xd+prototype+site:forums.adobe.com&newwindow=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFnuPn_rHZAhWCDJAKHTAlAMYQrQIISCgEMAE&biw=1280&bih=893

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oi,
 Na realidade adobe XD é uma ferramenta de design e prototipagem para designers. É bem parecido com o Sketch e Figma. São ferramentas para design. o Adobe XD hoje não oferece plugin para conversão em HTML e CSS, mas mesmo que oferecesse não resolve o seu problema que é colocar um dashboard no wordpress. O que você pode fazer é desenvolver o template e trabalhar no functions.php e colocar nas pastas do seu tema, porém para integrar com o wordpress e imprimir informações do painel, precisa rpogramar em PHP, colocar as variáveis corretas conforme documentação do wordpress etc.

Dá uma olhada nesse link também:https://digwp.com/2010/10/customize-wordpress-dashboard/

Comment: Não dá pra resolver com um simples html embedding?

Comment: Mesmo que de alguma forma você consiga o código com o xd, para fazer um arquivo e colocar num iframe ou alguma outra forma pra embed, isso não seria interativo. Se é um dashboard você precisa dele interativo certo? Sobre ideias pra embed do link, teoricamente funciona, porém o link não é vitalício até onde sei.